# How to implement Single Sign-On in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on

I am implementing Single sign-on in my developer edition. But the help documents are so unrelated or bit confusing anybody give the links where I can get clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most clear explanation for SSO via SAML in Salesforce.
[Single Sign-On with SAML on Force.com](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_with_SAML_on_Force.com).
But the main work will be on your server side. It depends on platform you want to use as Identify Provider.